# How to search words in text files faster than "grep" of linux command?

Tags: linux, search, grep

I have many files including code. I need to search function as well as different keywords. Currently I am using "grep -i -r 'keyword to search'" in linux to search. However, I need to increase searching speed to reduce time.

I have also heard about Boyer-Moore algorithm which is a fast searching one. But the result I have obtained isn't my expectation.

So I am very looking forward to hearing your comments and solutions

Comment: Do you really need the `-i` option? It is the one making things slower. Also, which files are you looking in? You can make use of `--include` and `--exclude`.

Answer (score 2):

- You should try `ack` ([homepage](http://beyondgrep.com/)). It is designed as fast search tool for code.
- If you want to have the ability to search your code with taking language syntax into account (distinguishing between functions and symbols) you should try [Exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

There are [several tools](http://betterthanack.com/) that are prospectively worthwhile, relative to the popular Ack. The first one that came to mind for me was The Silver Searcher.